# New tag wiki for the tag 'relay' doesn't represent previous usage of tag

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki

I came across this tag wiki edit:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7429349

Before this edit, there was no tag wiki for the tag yet.  The new definition of [relay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/relay): "Relay is framework from Facebook that..." is only valid for the most recent three questions in the tag.  Before that, there are another 95 questions.  At a glace, mostly about electrical (especially Arduino) relays or mail relays.

Doesn't really seem appropriate to co-opt the tag for this new framework.  On the other hand, not sure whether it was that terribly useful a tag in the first place.

I'd think a new tag should be created for the Facebook framework.  Would that be the right thing to do?

Comment: `[facebook*]` lists [a comprehensive set of tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook+or+facebook-graph-api+or+facebook-javascript-sdk+or+facebook-like+or+facebook-fql+or+facebook-php-sdk+or+facebook-opengraph+or+facebook-c%23-sdk+or+facebook-login+or+facebook-ios-sdk+or+facebook-android-sdk+or+facebook-apps+or+facebook-comments+or+facebook-access-token+or+facebook-oauth+or+facebook-page+or+facebook-social-plugins+or+facebook-sharer+or+facebook-wall+or+facebook-authentication); `facebook-relay` is a good option IMO, keeping `relay` as a general tag.

Comment: facebook-relay seems appropriate, and facebook-graphql for the other tag introduced in the same questions.

Comment: Undid the damage as well as possible. Trouble is, I cannot fathom what to write, so it's a bit non-descript now. (Cannot simply revert it as it was the first edit.)

Comment: I was going to edit the newest three questions and suggest [tag:facebook-relay]. However ... reading those questions did not convince me of its usability. One is asking for tools etc., the other two look sorta open questions to me. Would anyone else (except the OP of those three!) be bothered by closing them all?

Comment: All 3 questions are now On Hold, so, for now, the question is moot. If and when Facebook Relay is actually released, a [facebook-relay] tag can be used for questions about it.