# Can we relay the [facebook-relay] tag to [relayjs]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

I just observed that the [facebook-relay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook-relay) tag has 6 questions and the [relayjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/relayjs) tag has 194 questions, and since they are both about [Relay javascript framework](https://facebook.github.io/relay/), I propose to synonymise [facebook-relay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook-relay) or burninate it altogether since there is no [facebook-react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook-react)[facebook-graphql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook-graphql) tags.

We should also deal with the [relay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/relay) tag (74 questions) that [doesn't represent the previous usage of the tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288567/new-tag-wiki-for-the-tag-relay-doesnt-represent-previous-usage-of-tag).

Comment: Thanks for posting this burnination request and allowing the community to take a close look at it. Please note that burninations are not just tag removals - They are the process of carefully moderating a specific place of Stack Overflow. Avoid only mass-editing the tag out of questions as it is counter-productive. Flag/vote/edit/retag the posts after consensus is reached. For more info, see [Shog9's answer on MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191/306392) or the [unofficial SOCVR process](https://github.com/SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers/SOCVR-RoomInformation/blob/master/burnination.md#process).