# Merge Tags [relayjs] & [relay]

Tags: discussion, retag-request

The two tags [relayjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/relayjs) and [relay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/relay) are referring to the exact same thing, and it's unclear which to use, so using both seems to be the only option right now. Can we merge these tags?

Also, [this SO Meta discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288567/new-tag-wiki-for-the-tag-relay-doesnt-represent-previous-usage-of-tag) suggested renaming the tag completely to `facebook-relay`, though not sure that's as appropriate now that it's becoming more open-sources/generic. Ex: you wouldn't rename `reactjs` to `facebook-react`.

Comment: What do you want to merge into what?

Comment: Not sure I really care, though `relayjs` seems to be slightly more used than `relay`, and it's a bit more specific, so maybe merge `relay` into `relayjs`?

Comment: So all posts in relay are all about relayjs?

Comment: No, a few (as noted in the linked discussion) are about other things called `relay`, though most are about Facebook's `realyjs`. I could identify the few non-relayjs related questions?

Comment: Yeah, those need to retagged correctly. Now i hope a mod or CM can complete this request. Not sure where this request will go on their backlog.

Comment: I can retag them, but what should they be retagged as? I sort of feel that we should just kill the `relay` tag completely since it's too generic.

Comment: On the ones that are not about relayjs, you either remove the tag relay or retag it to something else that makes sense. What is left in relay will become relayjs, I hope automagically

Comment: I'll get it done tonight

Comment: I have removed the `relay` tag from all non `relayjs` questions (there were only a few of them).

Comment: both are still being used

Comment: Is there a way to stop creation of the tag? I can remove it again, but it would just be a chicken/mouse game.